# Is my while loop flawed or is it just going to take a long time to finish?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, infinite-loop, fibonacci

While coding in python 3 I developed a while loop that seemed to be taking forever to finish loading.  I don't understand why it's not working and whether or not its going to run infinitely so if anybody can see my error please point it out.

```
list = [1,2]
Conditional = list[-1] < 4,000,000
while Conditional:
    def fibonacci(first,second):
        first = first + second
        list.insert(-1,first)
        second = first + second
        list.insert(-1,second)
fibonacci(1,2)
```

Comment: Did you mean `if Conditional:`?

Comment: Was the call to fibonacci supposed to be indented? (i.e., within the loop body)?  If so, should it's arguments be taken from list?  Also: why are `first` and `second` computed as the same thing?  (It seems like `second` just shouldn't be there.)

Comment: If Conditional isn't changed in the while loop, it will go on for ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Reblochon Masque answer will actually return the last number as higher than 4,000,000. You need to check the last element before appending.

If I would write the function, I'd do something like this:

```
def fibonacci(data, n):
   fb = data[-1]+data[-2] #
   while fb < n:
       data.append(fb)
       fb = data[-1]+data[-2]
   return data

mylist = [1,2]
limit = 4000000
output = fibonacci(mylist,limit)
```

Notes on your original code:

- You were defining your function inside loop (i'm not sure if it's even accessible).
- I wouldn't use 'list' as a name since list is a built-in function
- I would use append to insert as a last element.

Answer (score 2):

#### This loop never ends:

`Conditional = list[-1] < 4,000,000` is always True, therefore, `while Conditional:` is equivalent to `while True`

If you want all fib numbers under 4,000,000, you could do like this:

```
fibs = [1,2]
while fibs[-1] < 4000000:
    fibs.append(fibs[-2] + fibs[-1])
```